# Test cases in C for WIFSIGNALED, WIFSTOPPED, WIFCONTINUED

Tags: c, signals, waitpid

I'm playing with waitpid() and signal() and I'm looking for reliable test cases for returning WIFSIGNALED(status) = WIFSTOPPED(status) = WIFCONTINUED (status) = true but can't find any...

Care to tell me how can I make sure those return true so I can debug my code?

Also, a few hints about what signals should I catch with signal() to test those macros would be helpful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof (x)[0])

static void testsignaled(void) {
   kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
}

static void teststopped(void) {
   kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
}

static void testcontinued(void) {
   kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
   /* Busy-work to keep us from exiting before the parent waits.
    * This is a race.
    */
   alarm(1);
   while(1) {}
}

int main(void) {
   void (*test[])(void) = {testsignaled, teststopped, testcontinued};
   pid_t pid[NELEMS(test)];
   int i, status;
   for(i = 0; i < sizeof test / sizeof test[0]; ++i) {
      pid[i] = fork();
      if(0 == pid[i]) {
         test[i]();
         return 0;
      }
   }
   /* Pause to let the child processes to do their thing.
    * This is a race.
    */
   sleep(1);
   /* Observe the stoppage of the third process and continue it. */
   wait4(pid[2], &status, WUNTRACED, 0);
   kill(pid[2], SIGCONT);
   /* Wait for the child processes. */
   for(i = 0; i < NELEMS(test); ++i) {
      wait4(pid[i], &status, WCONTINUED | WUNTRACED, 0);
      printf("%d%s%s%s\n", i, WIFCONTINUED(status) ? " CONTINUED" : "", WIFSIGNALED(status) ? " SIGNALED" : "", WIFSTOPPED(status) ? " STOPPED" : "");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Handling WIFSIGNALED is easy.  The child process can commit suicide with the `kill()` system call.  You can also check for core dumps - some signals create them (SIGQUIT, IIRC); some signals do not (SIGINT).

Handling WIFSTOPPED may be harder.  The simple step to try is for the child to send itself SIGSTOP with the `kill()` system call again.  Actually, I think that should work.  Note that you may want to check on SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU and SIGTSTOP - I believe they count for WIFSTOPPED.  (There's also a chance that SIGSTOP only works sanely when sent by a debugger to a process it is running via the non-POSIX system call, `ptrace()`.)

Handling WIFCONTINUED is something that I think the parent has to do; after you detect a process has been stopped, your calling code should make it continue by sending it a SIGCONT signal (`kill()` again).  The child can't deliver this itself; it has been stopped.  Again, I'm not sure whether there are extra wrinkles to worry about - probably.

Answer (score 1):

A framework something like the below will allow you check the results of the `wait()` and `waitpid()` calls.

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    /* child */
    sleep(200);
}
else {
    /* parent */
    kill(pid, SIGSTOP);

    /* do wait(), waitpid() stuff */
}
```

You do not actually have to catch the signals (using `signal()` or related function) that are sent. `signal()` installs a handler that overrides the default behavior for the specific signal - so if you want to check for a signal terminating your process, pick one that has that default behavior - "`man -s7 signal`" will give you details a signal's default behavior.

For the macros you have mentioned use `SIGSTOP` for `WIFSTOPPED(status)`, `SIGCONT` for `WIFCONTINUED (status)` and `SIGINT` for `WIFSIGNALED(status)`

If you want more flexibility for testing, you could use kill (see "`man kill`") to send signals to your process. `kill -l` will list all the signals that can be sent.

Comment: The same as I commented above, what I'm most looking for is the specific signals to test those macros. There's a problem though, how can I check the WIFSTOPPED if I can't handle SIGSTOP?

Comment: @Ricardo, you can't handle `SIGSTOP` in the child; `WIFSTOPPED` is meant for use in the parent:  `if( pid != 0 && WIFSTOPPED( status ) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score -1):

in your tests you can fork() and send specific signal to your child processes? In this scenario your child processes are test cases?

**EDIT**

my answer is about coding a C test. you fork, get the pid of your child process (the process
with signal handlers installed), then you can send signal to it by using `kill(2)`. 
In this way you can test the exit status

Comment: Of course I already have that, I'm looking for the specific signals, which one will produce which macro equal to true... How can I send them through the bash to a specific process so I can test them, that's what I want to know.