# How to detect that a child process has crashed?

Tags: c, linux

A child process can:

- Exit normally (by exiting using `exit(0)`,`exit(22)`, `exit(23)`) -- This is obviously specific to my application
- Exit abnormally (code throws an exception, receives an unhandled signal, core dumps, etc...)

I am doing a fork/exec from a parent process and looping on [`waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), when I detect that child process has exited I would like to determine the reason it exited.

Currently I check `WEXITSTATUS(status)` (where `status` is returned by [`waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)) to determine exit code.

Is there a way to reliably detect if child exited abnormally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for `WIFSIGNALED(status)`. For testing this check out [Test cases in C for WIFSIGNALED, WIFSTOPPED, WIFCONTINUED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907867/test-cases-in-c-for-wifsignaled-wifstopped-wifcontinued).

Of course you can also do a positive check for normal termination with `WIFEXITED(status)`.

Comment: would that be enough to detect if process has crashed without receiving a signal?

Comment: @Kam: There's no such thing. "Crash" is not technical concept.

Comment: @Kam If your program crashes it should do so for example with a SIGSEGV or a SIGBUS.

Comment: @Kam You are welcome. Feel free to accept my answer when you tested that my suggestions work for you.